# Changed array value in foreach loop doesn't stick

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a `foreach` loop that should change the value of one of the settings in the "settings" array. However this does not stick outside of the `foreach` loop. The entire function:

```
    public function GenerationModifiers(){
    $query = "SELECT `modifiers` FROM `settings`";
    $data = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    $modifiers = $row['modifiers'];
    $modifiers = explode(";", $modifiers);
    foreach($modifiers as $modifier){
        $mod = explode(".", $modifier);
        $control = $mod[0];
        $setting = $mod[1];
        switch($control){
            case "moduleOff":
                $modules[$setting]['enabled'] = 0;
                print_r($modules[$setting]);
                break;
            case "settingsChange":
                $s = explode(":", $setting);
                $toChange = $s[0];
                $changeTo = $s[1];
                $this->settings[$toChange] = $changeTo;
                print_r($this->settings[$toChange]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This function is located in a class which also has a very similar constructor, that also sets `$this->settings;`
Where it's used in page generation:

```
class pageGeneration {
    public function __construct($settings, $version, $dbc, $layout, $core, $parser, $admin){
        $this->settings = $settings;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->core = $core;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->admin = $admin;

    }
    public function Generate(){
        $this->core->GenerationModifiers(); ... //More unneeded code here
```

I've seen people do it like this;

```
foreach($modifiers as &$modifier){
```

But that won't work here as I'm changing the "settings" array, right?

Comment: Do your values print when you call `print_r`? If not your `$control` variable probably doesn't have the values you're expecting.

Comment: @Cfreak Yes, that's how I know that they change within the `foreach` but not outside of it.

Comment: what does the data look like before you start calling explode? (the value of `$modifier`)

Comment: @Cfreak It looks like: `moduleOff.forums;settingsChange.home_display:test`

Comment: @Cfreak Actually, that's incorrect. It would be `Array ( [0] => moduleOff.forums, [1] => settingsChange.home_display:test )`

Comment: Is `$modules` visible in the scope of this piece of code? Or is it just creating a new `$modules` in this scope?

Comment: Same questions as @RiggsFolly but for `$this->settings`.  I think something else in your code is redefining things. When you tested it did you print the settings right after the loop or in some other part of the code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, currently modules wouldn't be visible, but what I'm looking for is how to change the settings one first, because once I know how to do that I can change the way the modules variable works.

Comment: @Cfreak If you would like I could post the entire code for where that function is used in the page, there would just end up being a lot of code. Two classes to be exact.

Comment: That would be very useful

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added what I believe should be all of the relevant code that you will need.

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, the GenerationModifier function is in a class called Core. I could move it to the page generation class if that would make this work properly, though.

Comment: I think this is scope issue. Try `$this->core->GenerationModifiers($this->settings);` and change the called function to use `public function GenerationModifiers(&$settings){` etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly That didn't seem to help the situation, do you think moving the function to the page class would resolve that?

Comment: So the issue is the `$this->settings` variable is not a class variable of `GenerationModifiers` you need to pass it as `&$settings` and reference it as `$settings`.  Moving the function to the other class would work too. Or you could make GenerationModifers a subclass

Comment: @Cfreak, so I moved the function to the class that it needed to be in, that fixed the settings problem, but if the module loader is in Core, and I need to change information in the modules array, wouldn't I need that function to be with this one in the page generation class for it to change the modules array properly?

Comment: See answer, more room to manouver in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be sure we are singing off the same song sheet I have put what I said in an anwer. If it turns out to be fooy I will delete this.

```
public function GenerationModifiers(&$settingsIN){      //<-- changed

    echo 'In GenerationModifiers before trying to change';
    print_r($settingsIN);

    $query = "SELECT `modifiers` FROM `settings`";
    $data = mysqli_query($this->dbc, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    $modifiers = $row['modifiers'];
    $modifiers = explode(";", $modifiers);
    foreach($modifiers as $modifier){
        $mod = explode(".", $modifier);
        $control = $mod[0];
        $setting = $mod[1];
        switch($control){
            case "moduleOff":
                $modules[$setting]['enabled'] = 0;
                print_r($modules[$setting]);
                break;
            case "settingsChange":
                $s = explode(":", $setting);
                $toChange = $s[0];
                $changeTo = $s[1];
                $settingsIN[$toChange] = $changeTo;      //<-- changed
                print_r($settingsIN[$toChange]);         //<-- changed
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Called from

```
class pageGeneration {
    public function __construct($settings, $version, $dbc, $layout, $core, $parser, $admin){
        $this->settings = $settings;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->dbc = $dbc;
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->core = $core;
        $this->parser = $parser;
        $this->admin = $admin;

    }
    public function Generate(){
        print_r($this->settings);  // loop before you leap

        $this->core->GenerationModifiers($this->settings); 

        echo 'settings on return from core method call';
        print_r($this->settings);  // loop after we leapt
```

Comment: Ah now we have 2 `$settings` Will look at that!

Comment: Yes, this did work while having the function in the Core class. Now, to change the modules setting the correct way

Comment: Ok try now, I called the method Param `$settingIN` its ugly but stops confusion between the exploded value you called `$settings`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for all of your help